# vim - Autosave file to disk, efficiently

Tags: vim, automation, gvim, vimrc

I keep a log file, and want it to be written to disk without having to manually save it after every edit.

I've used the `:au! CursorHoldI,CursorHold <buffer> silent! :update` command that I found somewhere, and that works well, and is efficient: with `'updatetime'` of 4 seconds by default, it will write the file to disk (only if changed, hence `:update`, not `:write`) after the cursor has been in the same place for 4 seconds, in both *insert* and *normal* modes. (While the buffer has focus within Vim. Whether or not Vim has focus, which is a subtle point. That is, if Vim loses focus, the file is still saved after 4 seconds.)

The only problem is that if I have another file open with `:split`, and click or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd> there, then the original file is not saved after `'updatetime'` ms. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add the `BufLeave` event, making a command like this:

```
:au! CursorHoldI,CursorHold,BufLeave <buffer> silent! :update
```

In my `.vimrc` (aka `_vimrc`), I've defined

```
noremap <C-S-F5> :au! CursorHoldI,CursorHold,BufLeave <buffer> silent! :update<CR>
```

So that I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in that buffer to put it into autosave mode.

Note: the `silent` will not print any message, and `silent!` will also not print any errors, and ignore them. This is for buffers that do not have associated files, and read-only files.

Answer (score 1):

The `:wall` command (more commonly used by the abbreviated `:wa`) will, just like `:update`, only write a file if it is saved. The difference is, it will write ALL open files, not just the current one.

You could use the same autocmd you have, and just use `:wa` in place of `:update`.

Comment: Right! I didn't realise that `:wa` will only write changed files. It should really be called "`:updateall`". Also, then `silent!` is not necessary — `:wall` checks for non-file and read-only buffers.